# How to delegate Windows Azure account to another Live Id account

Tags: azure, account, windows-live-id

I have a live id account and a subscription to Windows Azure.
I would like to delegate (or add additional) account to the same Windows Azure subscription.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: This should be asked on ServerFault or SuperUser, not on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is add a co-administrator to your Windows Azure Subscription by providing email address (Microsoft account) of the co-administrator. To do so, go to the portal and click on `SETTINGS` and then `ADMINISTRATORS` tab and then click on `ADD` icon on bottom as shown in the screenshot below. The co-administrator would then have the capability to login into Windows Azure Portal and manage that subscription there.

[image]